How to check if $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_n)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified?
Consider a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb Q_p[x]$ and consider its iterates $f^{\circ n}(x)$. Let $\alpha_n \in \bar{\mathbb Q}_p$ such that $f^{\circ n}(\alpha_n)=0$ for all $n \geq 1$.
Suppose, I proved that successive extensions of the tower $$\mathbb{Q}_p \subset \mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_1) \subset \mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_2) \subset \cdots \mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_n)\subset \cdots $$
are totally ramified, i.e., $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_n)/\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_{n-1})$ is totally ramified. To avoid confusion, let $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_0)=\mathbb{Q}_p$.
We know that compositum of totally ramified extensions may not be totally ramified.
How to check if $\mathbb{Q}_p(\alpha_n)/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified?
I simply ask for those possible methods which might give me a answer either positive or negative.

A compositum of totally ramified extensions may not be totally ramified, but a tower of totally ramified extensions always is---ramification degree is multiplicative in towers.

I am writing a self-answer with the above hints.
Consider the tower: $F \subset K \subset L$ of totally ramified extensions, that is, $K/F$ and $L/K$ are totally ramified with ramification indices $e_{K/F}$, $e_{L/K}$ respectively.  Moreover, assume $P, Q, R$ are primes in $F, K, L$ respectively.
Since $K/F$ and $L/K$ are totally ramified, the primes $P$ and $Q$ factor in the extensions $K$ and $L$, respectively, as
\begin{align}
P&=Q^{e_{K/F}} \\
Q&=R^{e_{L/K}}
\end{align}
Thus, the prime $P$ factor in the final extension $L$ is $P=\left(R^{e_{L/K}} \right)^{e_{K/F}}=R^{e_{K/F} \cdot e_{K/F}}$. Hence, the ramification index of $L/F$ is the product $e_{K/F} \cdot e_{K/F}$.
